# Getting rid of New Game+ (or +2) in Rogue Legacy

Tags: rogue-legacy

I beat Rogue Legacy twice recently and I'm now at New Game +2, however, I don't like it. It's too difficult for me. Is there a way to go back to New Game+ without re-doing everything? I have located the save files but opening in notepad doesn't really tell me anything. Is there a way to edit the save files, or even an in-game option?